# Transfering ETH from Account 1 to 2

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm trying to transfer ether from an Account 1 to an Account 2. This is the code:

```
function pay(address _from, uint256 _tokenId) external payable noReentrant {
    uint256 balance = msg.sender.balance;
    require(balance > 0.011 ether, "There is not enough eth");        

    payable(__ADDRESS2__).transfer(0.001 ether);
}

receive() external payable {
}

fallback() external payable {
}
```

So here the msg.sender is Account 1 and this account wants to transfer eth to Account 2. Both accounts have ethers but it's throwing this error:

*Error: Transaction reverted: function call failed to execute*

I'm using hardhat to test this function. So I have a couple of doubts:

1. Is this the correct way to transfer tokens from Account 1 to 2? And here I'm not talking about transfering eth from Account 1 to address of the contract.
2. If it is, then, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Questions about Ethereum might get a better response at [ethereum.SE], Stack Overflow's sister site dedicated to Ethereum .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the code you presented trasnfers ether from the contract to *ADDRESS2*, so the transaction probably reverts because the contract doesn't have enough ether. You should've checked that the caller sends you enough ether to transfer, i.e `require(msg.value >= 0.001 ether)`.

Concerning the last two questions:

1. No, this code illustrates ether transfers. If you want to transfer ERC20 tokens, the [OZ library](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc20) would be a good start.
2. The reason it reverts is explained above. Sending ether is very different from sending ERC20 (or any other) tokens, consider checking the OpenZeppelin library.

Comment: Ive tried this, setting up the msg.value parameter but now I have anoher doubt, that ether that send as msg.value, is going to be removed from the account that calls that pay function, right? Because Ive tried this and I see that with msg.value the contract has these ethers but they arent removed from the sender account.

Comment: Okey, doubt resolved. So the ethers are automatically removed from the sender account and send to the contract account and from there, given to the different accounts. Thank you anyway!